# How to identify HTML tag changes After page reload

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, extjs, selenium-webdriver

In my company we have single page web application which is developed in ExtJS. 
In main page wherever I change any value in drop-down application will add new HTML tag at bottom of main page. 
I wants to known about the HTML tag added\removed after selecting drop-down. In short i wants to know the HTML code difference between two stage.

Is there any tool or API using which I can differentiate it and use in my automation script.

Comment: You could compare the actual HTML of one page to the other. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect DOM changes (check for changes in elements order)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383461/detect-dom-changes-check-for-changes-in-elements-order)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Just select a value from the dropdown and when the new tag appears, inspect it. Do you need to know *all* the changes or just a specific one?

Comment: Comment by Dekel is what I want to achieve.... Thanks...