# Subscribing to DOM changes using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

We have a number of third-party and first-party jquery plugins which are adding and removing elements from the current DOM. Is there a mechanism native to javascript or jquery which would allow us to subscribe to the addition and removal of elements in the DOM?

We want to be able to observe newly added elements as well as see elements which are being removed.

Is this possible? Is yes, can anyone help with references to specs, samples, etc...?

If it helps... on our case we would be interested in elements or fragments which contain certain attributes.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383461/detect-dom-changes-check-for-changes-in-elements-order/40383782#40383782

Comment: does it answer your question? Please let me know if something else is needed.