# Listening for specific DOM element insertion

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script that lets me delete all iFrames from a page by pressing a button:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   var addButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   addButton.innerHTML = "DELETE iFRAMES";
   addButton.onclick = removeAllIFrames;
   document.body.appendChild(addButton);
});

function removeAllIFrames() {
    var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
    for (var frame of iFrames) {
        frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
    }
}
```

While this works, I was wondering if it was possible to listen for iFrame insertions and just delete them as they appear on the page. Is there some sort of `window.listenToElementInsertionByTag()` method so I can automate this? Otherwise I could just use a `setInterval()` and execute the `removeAllIFrames()` method on an interval.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383461/detect-changes-in-dom-elements-order/40383782#40383782 regarding `MutationObserver`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in DOM elements order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383461/detect-changes-in-dom-elements-order)

Comment: But note that in your case you only need `childList: true, subtree:true` in your Observer's config. Also, if you know a common ancestor to all these iframes, observe this common ancestor only, and if you know they will all appear at the same level, don't add the `subtree`.