# Replacing DOMSubtreeModified with MutationObserver - non jQuery

Tags: javascript

Looking to change from using DOMSubtreeModified to mutation observer in a non-jQuery script.

Current code to process document links looks like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", transform, false);

function transform(e) {
    if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
        processLink(element);
    }
    if (element.getElementsByTagName) {
        var a = element.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = a.length; i--; i > 0) {
            processLink(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3), but it uses jQuery and am not sure about what goes in the *do something* part.  Tried reading other docs on Mutation Observers but didn't get very far.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383461/detect-changes-in-dom-elements-order/40383782#40383782 there is a good example there. I know there is jquery in the answer, but it's not related to the MutationObserver part

Comment: Does it help? Let me know

Comment: @Dekel - It helps, thanks.   Need to figure out the right target and the  "// You can check the actual changes here" part.